# JS Ajax OnClick: How to execute php code multiple times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html button with an onclick attribute which runs a jQuery AJAX function pointing to php code.
 The php code writes HTML in an output HTML `<select>` element(the element remains hidden until the javascript runs.)
This is working great to populate the `<select>` when an "add another" button is clicked.

The problem is it adds one and only one. I want to be able to have a new `<select>` tag populate with *each* click of the "add another" button up to a max of 2.
The JS in question:

```
var genre_dropdown = function genre_dropdown() {
  $('.genre_output').css('display', 'block');
  $.ajax({
      url:'../includes/functions/genre_dropdown.php',
      complete: function (response) {
      $('.genre_output').html(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function () {
          $('.genre_output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

The HTML in question:

```
  <select name="genre_id[]" autocomplete="off" class="genre_output"></select>
  <select name="genre_id[]" autocomplete="off" class="genre_output"></select>
  <div class="button add-genre-button" onclick="return genre_dropdown();">+ Add Existing Genre</div>
```

I thought I could include 2 html `<select>` elements for the php to populate into, the code would execute from one to the next. I see why this is not correct, the code is running in both at the same time. I'm at a place where I'm considering have 2 buttons ("add one", "add another") but that seems redundant and not correct, especially considering I want a scale-able technique (the max may not always be 2.) I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php request is fine.

I simply mean define a variable as your  using javascript i.e.:

```
var sel = '<select name="genre_id[]" autocomplete="off" class="genre_output">' + response + "</select>';
```

and then each time you do a request it will include the response as the value of the element.  This would allow you to append the parent div as many times as you want.  Finally, use a simple if counter to decide whether to keep appending or not:

```
if ($(".genre_output").length <= 2){
   $("PARENT_DIV_ID").append(sel);
};
```

Is this clearer? @kaari

Comment: How would this work with php? I would describe the html elements as "templated" in the php file? This answer is unclear.

Comment: When I try this, what get inserted into the select elements is "[object Object]" instead of the results of the php code.

Comment: This isn't bad news, at least your divs are getting info.  Is your php function passing an array? Does it consist of objects? If this is the case you need only use some JavaScript to convert them to strings for display.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes that makes sense, thanks @Luke I will try that, thanks for  your help!

Comment: This code exactly worked EXCEPT 'response.responseText' was needed in lieu of just 'response'

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep previous values in dropdown then you can try append() instead of html()

```
$('.genre_output').append(response.responseText);
```